# Math.Round Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an output of

4.33 = 4.5

4.5517263843648 = 5

Using the Math.round function in javascript.  I've tried a few methods but neither seem to work.

Comment: Math.round(), Math.floor() and Math.ceil() always round to the nearest, lower and upper integer.  In order to round to the nearest integer or half integer you should make a function that does the math.  Stack Overflow is not a site to ask for someone else to do it for you. Post what you have tried

Comment: _"you should make a function that does the math"_... How does that help at all?

Comment: just ganna leave this here: `[1,2,1.2,1.8,1.5,1.3].map(function(v){return v + ": " + Math.round(v*2)/2}).join(", ")`

Comment: @GottZ: Did you get that from the answer on the duplicate link?

Comment: @Cerbrus nope i got it from trying it here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25068302#25068302

Answer (score 1):

Try to use,

```
function test(val) {
    var x = Math.floor(val);
    return (val - x) > 0.5 ? Math.ceil(val) : (x + 0.5);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qcq3p3bj/1/)

Comment: This answer doesn't work. `test(0.1)` returns `0.5`, `test(1.1)` returns `1.5`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thats what he asked for. Right?

Comment: He wants to round it to the nearest half.

Comment: @Cerbrus When did you read OP's mind? Don't speculate! Let OP speak up.

Comment: Your assumption that the OP always wants to round _up_ to the next `0.5` is just as much of a speculation. Besides, it's uncommon for a rounding function to always round in the same direction.

Comment: His examples clearly show that he wants the the next 0.5.
`4.5517263843648 = 5`

Comment: @Cerbrus The nearest half of 4.55 is 4.5. The upper half is 5.

Comment: Ugh, I'm blind as a bat. You guys are right.

Comment: @Cerbrus Haha, it happens..